# Prove that the each angle of regular hexagon is 120.

Tags: geometry

I need a theoretical proof that each angle of a regular hexagon is $120^\circ$.

Answer (score 2):

Sum of the internal angles of a regular Hexagon is $(2.6-4)*90=720 $ As there are 6 angles so each angle must be $720/6=120$

Another Perspective:In a regular Hexagon there are 6 Triangles each having the sum of the angles as $180$ degrees.So the sum of the  Angles of all the 6 triangles is $180*6$ but this contains the central angle of $360$ degree so the sum of the internal angles of the hexagon is $180.6-360=720$.As all the angles are same so each angle must be $120$ degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Draw the five radiuses from the hexagonal's center to its vertices. You get 6 congruent isosceles triangles whose basis angle's equals $\,x=\,$ half our wanted angle..

But then the central angle in each triangle equals $\,180^\circ-2x\,$ , so

$$6(180^\circ-2x)=360^\circ\Longrightarrow 180^\circ-2x=60^\circ\Longrightarrow 2x=120^\circ$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider a line rotating about a regular $n$-gon in
the Euclidean plane.
If the angle at each vertex is $a$,
then the line rotates $180-a$ at each vertex.

Since there are $n$ vertices,
the total rotation is
$n(180-a)$.

But this total rotation is
$360$.
So, $n(180-a) = 360$
or $a = 180 - 360/n$.

For $n = 6$, $a = 180-360/6 = 180-60 = 120$.

Note: This is not original by me.

Answer (score 0):

Divide a regular hexagon  into two equal trapezium and sum of angels of each trapezium is 360 therefore 2 trapezium = 720 and 720 should be divide into 6 equal parts and it comes out to be 120